# ASP.NET MVC - Routing and Culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, culture

I have a base controller in which I get and set the `CurrentThread` **Culture**.

```
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        string cultureName = null;
        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
            cultureName = Request.UserLanguages[0]; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
```

Everything works fine. But now I realized that regarding SEO I will have some issues since probably not all my languages will be picked up.

So I thought about putting the `CurrentCulture` on the url :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SpecificCulture",
        url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            culture = Helpers.CultureHelper.GetCurrentNeutralCulture(),
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

However this doesn't work since my `RegisterRoutes` runs before my `BaseController` which means that the url does not refect the current selected culture, it does reflect the default culture.

So my question is : Is there anyway to update my routing maps after my culture is set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go though the below links it might help you to achieve what you want to

http://adamyan.blogspot.in/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207602/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC-Application-Par